# Close first pop up on button click when second button is clicked in JQuery datatables

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core, datatables

I am learning asp.NET Core, and currently I am working on Jquery data tables. I am facing a problem in data table. Please see attached image:

[image: Jquery datatable]

See, in the image, there is a View button for each row. When the View button is clicked, a Model pop up opens and displays information of Name and Position headers. After clicking on second View button for second row, first pop up remains open. I just want to turn off first pop up when we click for second pop up.
Following is the main code for onclick View button.

```
var Popup, dataTable;
$(document).ready(function () {
    dataTable = $("#employeetable").DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Employee/GetList",
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Name", "name": "Name" },
            { "data": "Position", "name": "Position" },
            { "data": "Office", "name": "Office" },
            { "data": "Age", "name": "Age" },
            { "data": "Salary", "name": "Salary" },
            {
                "data": "EmployeeID", "render": function (data) {
                    return "<a class='btn btn-default' onclick=PopupForm('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Employee")/" + data + "')>View</a>";
                },
                "orderable": false,
                "searchable": false,
                "width": "150px"
            }
        ],

        "serverSide": "true",
        "order": [0, "asc"],
        "processing": "true",
        "language": {
            "processing": "processing... please wait"
        }
    });
});
```

```
function PopupForm(url) {

    var formDiv = $('<div/>');

    $.get(url)
        .done(function (response) {
            formDiv.html(response);
            Popup = formDiv.dialog({

                autoOpen: true,
                resizable: false,
                title: 'Employee Details',
                height: 500,
                width: 700,
                close: function () {
                    Popup.dialog('destroy').remove();
                    /*formDiv.dialog('close');*/
                }

            });  
        });
}
```

Here is GitHub repo if above code is not enough: https://github.com/atif-dev/ServerSideProcessing

I have found some similar solutions about my issue here on Stack Overflow, but since I'm kind of NEWBIE in .NET Core, I didn't get the solution.

Comment: Your question does not appear to be a C#/.NET question, but rather a JavaScript question. More specifically, it is about whatever JavaScript library you are using to create the `formDiv.dialog({...})`.

Comment: Typically, in these cases, you would use a **[modal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) dialog** - for example, see [here](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) (but you may be using a different library - maybe BootStrap?). The `modal: true` setting means the user cannot open a second window until they close this first window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credit of my answer goes to @Jerry's Answer. Although the answer of @Jerry was not working, it redirected me to think as he was saying to destroy the first dialog box. Following is solution code. According to following code whenever a user clicks on View button the previously opened dialog box is destroyed because of statement `formDiv.dialog({ autoOpen: false })` and new dialog box opens because of statement `autoOpen: true`

Here is solution code:

```
var formDiv = $('<div/>');
function PopupForm(url) {
   /*formDiv = $('<div/>');*/
   formDiv.dialog({ autoOpen: false })
   $.get(url)
   .done(function (response) {
      formDiv.html(response);
      /*   console.log(formDiv)*/
      Popup = formDiv.dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      resizable: false,
      title: 'Employee Details',
      height: 500,
      width: 700,
      close: function () {
        Popup.dialog('destroy').remove();
        /*formDiv.dialog('close');*/
      }
     });
    });
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

By click the button you can destroy the previous dialog first, then initialize the next dialog.

```
var formDiv=$('<div/>');
formdiv.dialog({autoOpen:false}) //initialize an empty dialog to be destroyed

function PopupForm(url) {

var formDiv = $('<div/>');

$.get(url)
    .done(function (response) {
        formDiv.dialog('destroy').remove(); //destroy the previous one first
        formDiv = $('<div/>');
        formDiv.html(response);
        Popup = formDiv.dialog({

            autoOpen: true,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Employee Details',
            height: 500,
            width: 700
        });  
    });
}
```